# How to get the index of the selected item in a list box?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites

I want to get the index of the selected item in a Google Apps Script list box not the selected item itself. All of the examples I've seen so far create a server handler that gets the value of the list box through

```
var list1Value = e.parameter.list1;
```

I want to get the index though so I can index into an array. I tried to use this solution
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/services/vXa57-9T6E4
but my script complained that indexOf wasn't recognized

```
var currentmonth = months.indexOf(e.parameter.list1);
```

Anyone have a good idea on how to get the index? By the way this is a google apps script running in Sites not in Spreadsheets if that makes a difference.

Comment: What is `months` in your script?

Comment: I have a spreadsheet that I'm pulling months out of. It is just the standard January, February

Comment: `var phoneBillSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);

  var sheets = phoneBillSpreadsheet.getSheets();

  months = sheets[0].getRange(1, 2, 1, 11).getValues();`

  phoneBillData = sheets[0].getRange(3, 2, 6, 11).getValues();`

Comment: You have to be aware that getValues() returns a 2 dimensions array, you'll have to use the 'simple' array part of it to be able to use indexOf(). In your example it would be month[0] but I guess you know that ;-)

Comment: Yeah I figured that out implementing another function last night. Thanks for the heads up though. A newbie like me can use all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer doesn't make much sense since Google Apps Script is executed on Google's server, not in your browser and `indexOf()` is well recognized in GAS.

You should use an array with the elements of you listBox and then using `listArray.indexOf(listelement);` you'll get the index of the selected item.

example :

```
//in the UI construction 

var ItemlistArray = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];// note that this variable definition could be placed outside of the function so it becomes a global variable...
for (n=0,n<ItemlistArray.length;++n){
ListBox.addItem(ItemlistArray[n]
}

//in the Handler function

var item = e.parameter.listBoxName
var ItemlistArray = ['item1','item2','item3','item4'];// if ItemlistArray is global this line can be removed
var index = ItemlistArray.indexOf(item); // if for example the selected item was 'item3', index will be 2
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the UI construction part? You don't build the list of items using "Select cell"→Validation→Criteria→List of items.

Comment: Sorry,I have no access to my computer...I'm on Holliday's but be back soon:)