# GAS - define listBox() displayed value

Tags: google-apps-script, listbox

I have a form built and displayed in UiApp which uses the listBox class. My listBoxes are created as in the example below:

```js
var yearText = app.createListBox().setName("yearText")
                  .addItem("")
                  .addItem("Reception")
                  .addItem("Nursery");
```

When the form loads for the first time they default to display blank (the value at index 0). What I am trying to do is reload the form with stored data, populating the listBox with it's saved value whilst still offering the same options as above (blank, Reception, Nursery).

I have tried using the various `setValue` methods available to the `listBox` class but I am not making any progress (variations of `setValue` are working fine for `textArea`, `checkBox` and `dateBox` classes elsewhere in the form). Any help or guidance gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method for that is [setItemSelected(index,Boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/list-box#setItemSelected%28Integer,Boolean%29), example below

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var list = app.createListBox().addItem('').addItem('v2').addItem('v3').addItem('v4').setItemSelected(2,true);
  app.add(list);
  return app;
}
```

Or also : `setSelectedIndex(index)` (same link for doc

example below too

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var list = app.createListBox().addItem('').addItem('v2').addItem('v3').addItem('v4').setSelectedIndex(2);
  app.add(list);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Serge! As you can see from my example I've not specified index position, nor do I know how to extract it out in the same way as I do the value (`var yearTextValue = e.parameter.yearText`) but now you've put me on the right track I'm sure I'll get there. I was being lazy and hoping I wouldn't have to rework it too much...

Comment: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804081/how-to-get-the-index-of-the-selected-item-in-a-list-box and will be using this approach :-[]

Comment: I didn't catch that you needed also to get the listBox value, sorry about that. Don't forget that you can use 2 values in addItem : one "shown value" and one "returned value", if you use a number as returned value this number can be the index value itself thus making it simpler to use for setSelectedIndex. I don't see clearly what is your entire data flow so maybe I'm off subject... if so, feel free to provide more info. (in the mean time thx for accepting ;-)